# Performance problem on a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a performance problem on a query.

First table is a Customer table which has millions records in it. Customer table has a column of email address and some other information about customer.

Second table is a CommunicationInfo table which contains just Email addresses.

And What I want in here is; how many times the email address in CommunicationInfo table repeats in Customers table. What could be the the most performer query.

The basic query that I can explain this situation is;

```
Select ci.Email, count(*) from Customer c left join 
CommunicationInfo ci on c.Email1 = ci.Email or c.Email2 = ci.Email 
Group by ci.Email
```

But sure, it takes about 5, 6 minutes in execution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How many records in `CommunicationInfo`?

Comment: what is the relationship between `Customer`  and `CommunicationInfo`?  I'm thinking that there are many `CommunicationInfo` rows per `Customer` row, is that the case?

Comment: @KM: *Second table is a CommunicationInfo table which contains just Email addresses*. I believe it's a lookup table with each email only added once.

Comment: @Quassnoi, but is it one row for each time a communication was sent for the customer, or something like that.  if so it would be larger than the Customer table.

Comment: @KM: probably you're right. We need to wait for an answer then.

Comment: @KM: but in this case, your query will take forever :) If an email was sent 100 times to a customer, your query will return `100` records times the number of duplicates in `Email` times the number of duplicates in `Email2` for that email.

Comment: The CommunicationInfo table could change from thousand to a million. This table contains emails, which are collected from somewhere to make a campaign for existing customers and potentials. So I need to separate the emails, if any of them is used by an existing customer.

Thanks for your answers. I'll give a try for all your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this query is about as good as it gets if you have an index on Customer.Email and another on CommunicationInfo.Email

```
Select
    c.Email, count(*)
    from Customer c
        left join CommunicationInfo  ci on c.Email1 = ci.Email
        left join CommunicationInfo ci2 on c.Email2 = ci2.Email
    Group by c.Email
```

Comment: Key is Index. Make sure that email column is indexed properly.

Comment: If `ci.Email` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, this query is a synonym for `SELECT email, COUNT(*) FROM customer`. If it's not, this query is a messy cartesian join.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `OR` condition robs the optimizer of opportunity to use `HASH JOIN` or `MERGE JOIN`.

Use this:

```
SELECT  ci.Email, SUM(cnt)
FROM    (
        SELECT  ci.Email, COUNT(c.Email) AS cnt
        FROM    CommunicationInfo ci
        LEFT JOIN
                Customer c
        ON      c.Email1 = ci.Email
        GROUP BY
                ci.Email
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ci.Email, COUNT(c.Email) AS cnt
        FROM    CommunicationInfo ci
        LEFT JOIN
                Customer c
        ON      c.Email2 = ci.Email
        GROUP BY
                ci.Email
        ) q2
GROUP BY
        ci.Email
```

or this:

```
SELECT  ci.Email, COUNT(*)
FROM    CommunicationInfo ci
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  Email1 AS email
        FROM    Customer c
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  Email2
        FROM    Customer
        ) q
ON      q.Email = ci.Email
GROUP BY
        ci.Email
```

Make sure that you have indexes on `Customer(Email)` and `Customer(Email2)`

The first query will be more efficient if your emails are mostly not filled, the second one — if most emails are filled.

Comment: I have a feeling that since there are millions of records in the Customer table, hitting IO twice against wouldn't necessarily make it run faster, but the thought crossed my mind as well.

Comment: @Jeremy: as long as `Email` and `Email2` are indexed, this will just get all keys from two indexes in a sequential fashion. If all or almost all fields are filled and have a match, the same thing would need to be done, only in a less efficient nested loops (random read) fashion.

Comment: Ah yes, you mention that indexes need to be on the columns. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You mention:

> And What I want in here is; how many
>   times the email address in
>   CommunicationInfo table repeats in
>   Customers table. What could be the the
>   most performer query.

To me, that sounds like you could easily use an INNER JOIN - this would most likely be a lot faster, since it will limit the search scope to just those customers who really do have an e-mail - anyone who doesn't have an e-mail at all (and thus a count(*) = 0) will not even be looked at - that might make a big difference even just in the number of rows SQL Server has to count and group.

So try this:

```
SELECT 
   ci.Email, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
   dbo.Customer c 
INNER JOIN dbo.CommunicationInfo ci 
   ON c.Email1 = ci.Email OR c.Email2 = ci.Email  
GROUP BY
   ci.Email
```

How does that perform in your case??

Comment: It really takes so much time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment there may not be much you can do to optimize this.

A couple of questions:

1. How many records in CommunicationInfo?
2. How often do you really need to run this query? Is it a one time analysis, or are multiple people going to be running this every 10 minutes?
3. Are the fields indexed? I'll make a guess that neither Email1 nor Email2 field is indexed. However, I wouldn't suggest adding an index without taking the balance of the whole system into consideration.
4. Why are you using a left join? Do you really need EVERYTHING from the Customer table? You're counting, so no harm in doing an INNER JOIN.

Suggestions:

1. Run the query through the Query Optimization wizard to see if there is anything SQL Server would recommend.
2. An extreme suggestion would be to dump the Email1 and Email2 columns into a temp table and join to that. I've seen queries run slowly because of a large amount of stress on a particular table, so sometimes copying the records into a temp table is faster, but this technique is very dependent on how much memory there is, how fast IO is, and the amount of stress on a particular table.